# React + Electron + SQLite app error, Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'root\src\main\services'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, windows, sqlite, electron

I am building React + Electron + SQLite app using TS. It is about storing articles locally, and browsing them on your local computer. I am new to Electron (this is my first project).
In my Database.service.ts file i have my DB connection and CRUD functions. In my main.ts (main process) i have the handler for my functions, and i invoke them in preload.ts and then expose them through ContextBridge.
On my render side of the app (React) i try to call the functions. When i call getAllArticles function, it works fine, and i get all the data. But when i try to use my InsertArticle, i get the following error:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'path\src\main\services'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:

- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'

i did what they recommended and included  "path": require.resolve("path-browserify")  to my webpack.config.ts, but it didnt seem to solve anything.
As i mentioned above, i tried updating the Webpack.config.ts but it didnt seem to work. I have tried many other things (stack overflow prevois entries with similar problems, CHATgpt etc) but i couldnt find the solution to this.
Tried rebuilding, postinstall and many other things but it didnt solve anything
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this issue?
Thank you. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/JureArsovic/react-electron-sqlite3
Here is the code for the project. If anyone has any ideas how to fix it, please let me know. Any help is appreciated